# ResourceSupport getLinks() only has parent links in ResourceProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I am implementing a ResourceProcessor for a parent class, and when I do getLinks() within the *process* method, I only receive back links to self and to the parent. However when I actually request the resource, I get links to self, the parent, and the children...

Code:

```
@Bean
public ResourceProcessor<Resource<Parent>> ParentProcessor() {

   return new ResourceProcessor<Resource<Parent>>() {

     @Override
     public Resource<Parent> process(Resource<Parent> resource) {
         List<Link> links = resource.getLinks();
         //this list has links to 'self' and 'Parent'

         return resource;
     }
   };
}
```

However the JSON on requesting that resource looks as follows

```
"_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "rest/parents/1",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "parent" : {
       "href" : "rest/parents/1"
    },
    "child1" : {
      "href" : "rest/parents/1/child2"
    },
    "child2" : {
      "href" : "rest/parents/1/child2"
    },
```

}

Could anyone explain why this is the case?

EDIT: This turns out to be the case because the associated Entities are added by the ConversionService, which is unfortunately run AFTER the Processor is run. I'm curious as to whether or not there is a way to process after the ConversionService but in the meantime making a custom one seems to be the way to go

Comment: _"I'm curious as to whether or not there is a way to process after the ConversionService"_ And I would very much like to know the reason for that.

Comment: Okay... the use case involves needing to get only a couple of fields off of multiple rows of a resource with many associated entities. The result is that the _links section inflates the payload ~4x, so I was looking to remove the links to the child entities for that case. Even when using a projection revealing only the needed fields all links are still present. Obviously a solution is a custom controller, but once again I was simply 'curious' as to whether it was doable.

Comment: @pasquers Did you find a solution? Starting with spring boot 2 i have "?projection" contained in the link of a child which our client cannot process. I really need to modify this child link. Thanks for your reply!